# How to work Bootstrap datepicker?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

So I know there are plenty of threads and I've gone through the official [documentation](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) and tried the options laid out [here](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html), but this Datepicker is my mortal enemy and it simply never does what I, in any way, seek to do:

Currently (and for whatever reason) only future dates can be picked. I, on the other hand, want only dates that are longer than 21 years in the past to be pickable. Along with everything in the past. In fact, just having any dates in the past enabled would already help.

This is what I have at the moment - and to my surprise the DateFormat works - and in general Dates get saved.

```
  $('.datepicker').datepicker({
      format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
      endDate: '+0d',
      autoclose: true
  });
```

Working with this [gem](https://github.com/Nerian/bootstrap-datepicker-rails).

With every project no matter how complex or simple, this is the only problem I am having. Always, and ever :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
    startDate: '-Infinity',
    endDate: '-21y',
    autoclose: true
});
```

Comment: Yup, that's correct. I just figured out I was in the wrong view in my project where I made the edits. Coding for the past 18 hours. That was a brainfart deluxe of mine :P Will confirm the answer in a few minutes.